# AWS S3 file upload using cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-s3, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to implement file upload to amazon s3. I'm getting following error

```
Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\uri_template() (previously declared in /var/www/html/appname/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions‌​.php:17) File /var/www/html/appname/vendor/aws/GuzzleHttp/functions.php
```

In upload controller, using below code to upload

```
 require_once("../vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php"); 
 use Aws\S3\S3Client; 

 public function upload(){
   $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(   'version' =>
 'latest',   'region'  => 'ap-south-1',   'credentials' => array(
 'key' => 'key',
 'secret'  => 'secret'   ) ));

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
    if(!empty($this->request->data['file']['name']))
        {
            $fileName = $this->request->data['file']['name'];

                   $s3->putObject([
                        'Bucket'       => backetname,
                        'Key'          => $fileName,
                        'SourceFile'   => $this->request->data['file']['tmp_name'],
                        'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
                        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
                    ]);
         }                       

      }
}
```

Comment: Your HTTP client is conflicting, try this plugin https://github.com/mikesmullin/CakePHP-AWS-S3-Plugin

Comment: yeah you are right dileep, HTTP client is conflicting. How to resolve this conflict.

Comment: Thanks, trying now

Comment: No, that's plugin is old, may be it'll work for cakephp 2 and below, but I'm using cakephp 3.4. I have tried to implement, it's not working. Have u tried that plugin before?

Comment: Ok, add your code with the question.

Comment: Now working fine, but trying to upload I'm getting `Call to a member function putObject() on a non-object ` error. what's wrong with above code.

Comment: Seems that you are `$s3` is `null`, where you have loaded the model?

Comment: In upload controller

Comment: Add that code in your question as well.

Comment: Hi I added full code. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an object of S3 client outside of the method which is the reason that `$s3` in method is `null`.

Either you need to create object in method itself or you can store the S3 client object in class property and use with `$this->s3->putObject()`

Better would be to create a component, something like below:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Controller\Component;
 use Cake\Controller\Component;
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;

 class AmazonComponent extends Component{
    public $config = null;
    public $s3 = null;

    public function initialize(array $config){
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->config = [
           's3' => [
               'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
               'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
               'bucket' => 'YOUR_BUCKET',
           ]
        ];
        $this->s3 = S3Client::factory([
            'credentials' => [
               'key' => $this->config['s3']['key'],
               'secret' => $this->config['s3']['secret']
            ],
        'region' => 'eu-central-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
        ]);
    }
}
```

And use this component in your controller. Example below:

```
class UploadController extends AppController{
    public $components = ['Amazon'];

    public function upload(){
         $objects = $this->Amazon->s3->putObject([
                        'Bucket'       => backetname,
                        'Key'          => $fileName,
                        'SourceFile'   => $this->request->data['file']['tmp_name'],
                        'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
                        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
                    ]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Dilleep, Now I'm getting some error like this  `Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\uri_template() (previously declared in /var/www/html/appname/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php:17) 
File /var/www/html/appname/vendor/aws/GuzzleHttp/functions.php`, how to solve this error

Comment: Seems like your code still conflicting, you are not using the plugin ?

Comment: yes I'm not using.. is there any way to resolve that http conflict? I'm just following aws doc

Comment: In that case you need to create AWS component. Follow link https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component for creating a component.

Comment: Thanks Dileep. I did as exactly what u posted but now I'm getting this `error Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri::composeComponents() 
File /var/www/html/appname/vendor/aws/GuzzleHttp/Psr7/UriResolver.php 
Line: 102`

Comment: Did you installed AWS SDK with composer? if not then please install with composer, take help from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html. It seems some version issue.